# PHP XDebug how to interpet the Call Stack line indicators?

Tags: php, xdebug, callstack

when reading the XDebugger Call Stack, each line has a Time, memory usage, Function name and Location indication.

How must i interpet these Call Stack lines info?

- Are the time and memory indicators only of the function that was called or do these stack up with each new function call?
- Are the memory indicators of usage before, or after the function call on that stack line?

**Sidenote:**
i have read the documentation of xdebug but it did not clarify these questions for me. For this reason please restrain yourselfs from linking the official documentation. On the other hand, if you have found some sort of simple handy-guide for questions like these: those are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I honest don't have a direct answer because I never cared for those variables shown in XDEBUG. But have you considered finding that out yourself? All you need is to make a really big TXT file and cause an error. You should be able to see if the time is incremental or reset for every function call as well as the memory usage.

```
function foo() {
     longFunction();
     quickFunction();
     bigFunction(); // This will probably take a certain amount of time too.
     quickFunction(); // See if calling a small function again keeps the memory usage high.
     maybeCallUndeclaredFunction(); // I think this will cause stack to be shown.
}

function longFunction(){
    for($i = 0; $i < 999999999; $i++){

    }
}

function quickFunction(){
   return null;
}

function bigFunction() {
   $content = file_get_contents('big.txt');
}
```

Comment: thnx for the tip! i will wait till i get an awnser for my question, but this is definitely something worth looking into

Comment: You're welcome. My money is on the incremental values, btw. You can see at XDEBUG's documentation that a simple code that they execute have a timing of 0.001 and then 0.004.